# How to hide item from navbar if user is not an admin

Tags: angular

I want to hide in my navbar "Profile" item. Only user which got "admin" role can see this.
I already blocked Profile route and no only admin can activate this.

At the moment, it works so that no one sees (even admin) "profile" but if I enter "Profile" (localhost / profile (only admin can access this)) it starts to work as it should and the user with the admin role can be seen in the menu "profiles".

navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLogoutClick() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.flashMessage.show('You're logged out', {
      cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard<span></span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.adminloggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/login']">Log in</a>
          </li>
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;
  role: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}



  registerUser(user) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/register', user, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  checkRole(role) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/users/checkRole/' + role, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users/authenticate', user)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/users/profile', {
        headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }
  adminloggedIn() {
    if (this.role === 'admin') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

function `!authService.loggedIn()` works fine also `authService.loggedIn()`
but `authService.adminloggedIn()` doesn't works It looks like it starts only after entering /Profile

Comment: *ngIf needs a boolean value... the `adminloggedIn` function is not returning true/false

Comment: changed still nothing

Comment: `authService.adminloggedIn()` returns true or false or is it undefined?